# API hosted on Azure web app returns JSON Array with out the Name .Net core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-core

I have a web API Get.  That generates the correct  JSON response.  The application drops the `questions` name when I run the code on Azure.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Question>> Get()
    {
        var questions = _repo.GetQuestions();
        return Ok(new { questions });
    }
```

**local result**

```
    {
    "questions": [
        {
            "property": "test",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string",
            "label": "test ID",
            "constraints": {
                "minSize": "9",
                "maxSize": "10"
            }
        },
        {
            "property": "Email",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string",
            "label": "Email Address",
            "constraints": {
                "minSize": "1",
                "maxSize": "128"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Azure**

```
[
    {
        "property": "test",
        "required": true,
        "type": "string",
        "label": "test ID",
        "constraints": {
            "minSize": "9",
            "maxSize": "10"
        }
    },
    {
        "property": "Email",
        "required": true,
        "type": "string",
        "label": "Email Address",
        "constraints": {
            "minSize": "1",
            "maxSize": "128"
        }
    }
]
```

**Startup**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var connectionString = string.Empty;

        services.AddControllers(configure =>
        {
            configure.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true;//makes sure that content type is requested
        });

        services.AddDbContext<YLS_FAASTContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString(connectionString ));
        });

        services.AddScoped<IAPIRepo, APIRepo>();

        services.AddAuthentication("BasicAuthentication")
            .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, BasicAuthenticationHandler>("BasicAuthentication", null);

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {//prod only show 500 error
            app.UseExceptionHandler(appBuilder =>
            {
                appBuilder.Run(async context =>
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("An unexpected error has occured.  Try again later.");
                });
            });
        }


        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing something here. I tried the following code.

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class QuestionsController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Question>> Get()
    {
        var questions = new List<Question>(2);
        questions.Add(new Question()
        {
            property = "test",
            required = true,
            type = "string",
            label = "Test Id",
            constraints = new Constraints() { maxSize = "10", minSize = "9" }
        });

        questions.Add(new Question()
        {
            property = "Email",
            required = true,
            type = "string",
            label = "Email Address",
            constraints = new Constraints() { maxSize = "128", minSize = "1" }
        });

        return Ok(new { questions });
    }
}
```

And I am always getting the same response from local and azure.

Here is the response from Azure app service.

[image: JSON Response from Azure]

Here is the `Startup.cs` file.

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing.  Did you use .Net Core 3.1 to get this result?

Comment: Yes. I used .Net core 3.1

Comment: Can you please share your startup? I updated the code with my startup. Thank you.

Comment: I don't have anything specific in Startup.cs - I just created an API project that all